# Docker dns issue for a centos 7 container on ubuntu 16.04 Host

Tags: domain-name-system, docker

I saw many questions on the topic, but none solved my issue :

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 host,
On my brand new Centos 7 docker container, the system is not able to resolve any name:

In the container, for `/etc/resolv.conf`, google DNS is specified : `8.8.8.8`

`ping 8.8.8.8` is working fine, but `ping google.com` is not working

I thought it was a firewall problem, I purged the whole iptables at host side to permit everything : but the `ping google.com` is still not working (it seems hung)

Do you have any idea to resolve my DNS issue ?

Comment: Does `nslookup` work with Google or any other sites? Can you ping any other sites by name?

Comment: Do you have any other docker containers on this Ubuntu? Have this DNS issue on them?

Comment: Unfortunately, nslookup is not installed. yum install does not work because DNS resolution is not working... I tried to ping many FQDN servers, but none is working

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem : google DNS (8.8.8.8) was working at work... but not anymore ! I just changed /etc/resolv.conf with the new office DNS server and it works well.